# Check if image and thumbnail exist in directory or not

Tags: php

In this code I check if the image and its thumbnail are present in the directory using `file_exists()` function. With this code I don't get the thumbnail of the image which is not present in the directory, but I get the images which are not in it. How do I get the thumbnails of images which are not present in the directory? `$abc` and `$pqr` are the names of the arrays.

What should I do to get the image name and thumbnail which are not in the directory using `file_exists()`?

```
$vin1 = array();
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rr2s4_cma_images");
while ($q2=mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {
    $abc = $q2['image_name'];
    $pqr = $q2['type'];
    // $xyz[] = $abc."".$pqr;
    echo "<pre>";
    if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cribsuite/images/shortlistings/".$abc.$pqr) && ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cribsuite/images/shortlistings/".$abc."_thumb".$pqr)) {
        // ...
    } else  {
        // echo $abc."_thumb".$pqr. "&nbsp;The file doesn't exists";
        $img = $abc.$pqr;
        $thumb = $abc."_thumb".$pqr;
        $img1[] = $img;
        $thumb1[] = $thumb;
    }  
}
echo "<br>";
print_r($img1); 
print_r($thumb1);
```

Comment: What is the value of `$abc` and `$pqr`

Comment: $abc is a image name and $pqr is image extension which i fetch from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your mistake is in you `if` condition. `file_exists` function is not properly used.
>
> Remember your file extension variable $pqr is contain .(dot).

See e.g.,

```
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cribsuite/images/shortlistings/".$abc.$pqr)){
   // Do if origional image is exists.
}
else{
    // Do if origional image is not exists.
}
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cribsuite/images/shortlistings/".$abc."_thumb".$pqr)){
    // Do if thumbnail image is exists.
}
else{
    // Do if thumbnail image is not exists.
}
```

Comment: I try it but when i delete image from folder i also get the its thumbnail in array which is present into my folder.When i delete only image thumbnail from folder it doesn't show image thumbnail into my array.what i do?

Comment: If origional and thumbnail image both are exists then condition is true. I didn't get your query.

Comment: what i do if my original image is in the folder but its thumbnail is not into the folder?